# Date difference in PHP code does not execute

Tags: php, html, date, datetime-format, php-5.5

I have a code in PHP 5.5.11 where I am trying to do the following:

1. Get today's date in a variable --> $today
2. Calculate the end of month from a date in a form --> $st_dt_eom

if difference between these 2 dates is more than 5 days then execute a code. The code in the if condition below does not execute.

```
$today= date();

if($_POST['Submit']=='SAVE')
 {
    $st_dt=YYYYMMDD($_POST['st_dt'],"-"); 
    $st_dt_eom= datetime::createfromformat('YYYYMMDD',$st_dt);;
    $st_dt_eom->modify('last day of this month');
    $diff = $today->diff($st_dt_eom);
    $diffDays= intval($diff->format("%d")); //to get integer number of days

    if($diffDays>5){

     
     redirect("index.php");
     
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please try to limit your question to the actual problem.  As it stands, there's no way for us to even know if you're getting inside of the `=='SAVE'` check.  Take a few minutes and echo or debug out the values you're getting and compare those against wat you're expecting.  That will not only help you, but it will let us help you better as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example:

```
// 2022-12-19
$today = date('Y-m-d');

// $_POST['st_dt']
$st_dt = '2022-12-31';

function dateDiffDays($today, $st_dt)
{
    $today_obj= DateTime::createfromformat('Y-m-d', $today);
    $st_dt_eom= DateTime::createfromformat('Y-m-d', $st_dt);

    $diff = $today_obj->diff($st_dt_eom);

    return $diff->days;
}

// int(12)
$res = dateDiffDays($today, $st_dt);
```

use `var_dump` to locate your bug.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions to improve your code and produce something workable:

```
<?php

// Instead of using date(), use a DateTime() then you're comparing two DateTimes later on
$today = new DateTime();

// I'm assuming that your YYYYMMDD function removes "-" from the $_POST['st_dt'] 
// to provide a date in the format YYYYMMDD (or Ymd in PHP). 
// Unfortunately, DateTime doesn't understand that format. 
// So I'd change this for keeping Y-m-d (YYYY-MM-DD).
// Or modify your code to return that format!
$st_dt = $_POST['st_dt'];

// Watch out for your cAsE when using PHP functions! 
$st_dt_eom = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$st_dt);

$st_dt_eom->modify('last day of this month');
$diff = $today->diff($st_dt_eom);
$diffDays= intval($diff->format("%d"));
if($diffDays > 5){
   redirect("index.php");
}
```